# like запрос c с исключенным дефисом

Tags: mysql, laravel5, eloquent

Всем привет!
А можно ли в laravel5.5/eloquent/mysql 
составить “like” запрос  так
чтобы введя текст “A66” / “-A66” в поиске находились бы строки
“A-66” и “A66”
 ?
То есть символ дефиса как бы исключался и из условия и из текста?

И если да то как?

Спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

Паттерн наверно можно подобрать и покрасивее, но смысл не в нем.
Используем в запросе вместо `like` - `regexp`

```
$regexp = preg_replace('(-|\s)', '', ' A-6 6');
$regexp = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9])/', "-?\${1}", $regexp);
$models = Model::where('column', 'REGEXP', $regexp);
```

Comment: 1. Не `-?`, а `-*`. 2. Сюда только всякие injection'ы пропихивать типа `.*|`.